# Rename a field using a parameter in Kettle

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I am working on a transformation that gets data from a database table. After the Table Input step I would like to rename the primary key field to 'primaryKey'. The only way to get the name of the primary key field is through a parameter ${primaryKeyName}. How can I rename the field saved in the parameter ${primaryKeyName} to primaryKey?

I tried a Select Value step but it would use ${primaryKeyName} literally instead of getting the value of ${primaryKeyName}.

Comment: I think it might work if you renamed the field already inside the input step. Could you include a screen shot of your job, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use variables as field names to rename them unless:

option a) write your own User defined Java Class, fetch the variable name, and rename the field directly in Java;

option b) Use Metadata Injection to manipulate a template transformation: use a select values step in the inner/template transformation and have the outer transformation get the variable's value and use it to inject metadata into the Select values step

option c) it seems obvious, but can't you use an alias on your SQL query?

Comment: option a is what I went with. 

I'm not sure how option b would work.

option c is not an option because it is a 'select *' query. I'm not sure how to alias in a select *. I only know the primary key name at runtime.

Comment: I imagined as much about option c. As for b, watch the videos here: http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/ETL+Metadata+Injection